# How to access an auth0 object inside an html file from a js file

Tags: javascript, auth0

I have an html file as follow:

```
<body>
<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.23.1/lock.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var lock = new Auth0Lock(
       MyClientId, myDomain,{}
    )
lock.show();
</script>
</body>
```

Now I want to write the required functions for authentication inside a .js file.How can I access this Auth0Lock object ( I mean "lock" variable) in my .js file( as this lock object was defined inside my 'html' file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a global variable. In HTML, the global scope is the window object. All global variables belong to the window object.

If you declare your js file after the  block where you declared the lock variable, it  should be visible in using window.lock